# Only first object created can be saved to NSMutable dictionary in NSUserDefualts

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I have a method to increment a counter if it is the first time a user has been messaged on the particular day. Code below:

```
-(BOOL)canIncrementCountForUser: (NSString *)user {

    //erase the dictionary if it's a new day
    [self flushDictionaryIfNeeded];

    //load up a dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);

    //if empty it's a yes
    if([dictionary count]==0){
        NSLog(@"empty dictionary");
        NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user]; //do I need to set it back again?
        [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return YES;

    }

    //if it's not empty it's only a yes if the key doesn't exist
    else {

        //not in dict so unique
        if(![dictionary objectForKey:user]){
            NSLog(@"username we are checking is: %@",user);
            NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user]; //do I need to set it back again?
            [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            return YES;
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Already messaged %@ today!",user);
            //[dictionary removeAllObjects];
            //[defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
            //[defaults synchronize];
            return NO;
        }
    }
}

-(void)flushDictionaryIfNeeded{

    //set dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];

    if([dictionary count]>0) {

        //get any date
        NSDate *aDate = nil;
        NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
        aDate = [values objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateComponents *otherDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:aDate];
        NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        if([today day] == [otherDay day] &&
           [today month] == [otherDay month] &&
           [today year] == [otherDay year] &&
           [today era] == [otherDay era]) {

            NSLog(@"Don't flush");
        }
       else {

            NSLog(@"It's a new day! erase dictionary!");
            [dictionary removeAllObjects];
            [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }
    }
}
```

If a user is messaged a NSDate object will be created with the user's username as the key. If a key doesn't exist the counter can be incremented and the key is added, if it does exist the method returns false. I also have a method to erase all the contents if it's a new day.

I am having a strange problem. If the dictionary is empty and I pass a username though the method it will work fine and return true i.e can increment the counter so add the user to the dictionary. It will save this result and if I try to pass that string again it will tell me the user was already messaged as desired. However if I then put a new string through it, the code won't save the new object to the dictionary. I can keep passing the string and it says the user hasn't been messaged yet. If I restart the app and then try it again it will work and save the object to the dictionary, but any other strings used after that won't work. It will only save the first username key and object.. Could anyone give me any pointers to why this might be happening? It's very strange.

Comment: Add breakpoints, step through sections watching related variables. Finally: using NSUserDefaults is a bad idea, use a Data Model class and life will be easier.

Comment: What's wrong with using NSUserDefaults for simple variables or small arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Works as desired. I added

**dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];**

```
 -(BOOL)canIncrementCountForUser: (NSString *)user {

    //erase the dictionary if it's a new day
    [self flushDictionaryIfNeeded];

    //load up a dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);

    if (!dictionary) {
        dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    }
    // ...
}

- (IBAction)test1ButtonSelected:(id)sender {
    BOOL canIncrement = [self canIncrementCountForUser:@"test1"];
    if (canIncrement) {
        NSLog(@"yes, i can");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"can not");
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it a dictionary of a capacity 1? will this work for adding more than one key to the dictionary?

Comment: The capacity is just a hint to `NSMutableArray`, one can assume it is ignored. The dictionary will grow as needed. `dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];` works just as well